# failed to instantiate one or more class in android studio all my layout

Tags: android, android-layout, shared-libraries

I don"t how to explain this.I am just writing how It happens.

> compile 'com.muddzdev:styleabletoast:2.0.2'

I added this library from github. Ijust copy and pase ıt to my grandle. And now there is this in all my layouts.By the way  ; I don"t know why happens.My layout"s side (left and down) , There is black line.How can I fix these ?

```
    The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details java.lang.NullPointerException   at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getValue(Resources_Delegate.java:788)   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1286)   at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.loadFont(ResourcesCompat.java:212)   at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getFont(ResourcesCompat.java:206)   at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:152)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:81)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.<init>(CustomBar.java:95)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.StatusBar.<init>(StatusBar.java:67)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createStatusBar(Layout.java:224)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:146) Copy stack to clipboard
```

My build.grandle(Project:kkk(project name)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {  maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
       }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My build.grandle(Module.app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "something.about.berkay.kkk"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.muddzdev:styleabletoast:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: I tried this in one of my projects and that library seems to work fine for me. I'm wondering if you just need to File/Invalidate Caches/Restart. Let me know if that works or if you need more help tracking down the cause.

Comment: It is still exist.I used to invalidate and restart button and just restart .By I have created new project and I have used to library.It works.